# How to print html script dynamically with php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Using php I printed an `<script>` tag and some JavaScript lines. It worked as it should have.
Script I'm printing includes generate some objects from a library I'm using. However, when I want do that according to some condition, in this case, a for cycle I can't get it working.

This is the code I tried first:

```
<?php
$teacher1 = "teacher1";
echo "
<canvas id=\"lienzoGrafo\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\"></canvas>

    <script languaje=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"UTF-8\">

    var grafo = arbor.ParticleSystem({repulsion: 3000, friction:.1, stiffnes:900, gravity:true});
    grafo.renderer = Renderer('#lienzoGrafo')
    var teacher1 = grafo.addNode(\"$teacher1\",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:\"$teacher1\"})
```

As can be seen in last line of code I'm actually using a php variable for completing the script printing.

However, when I try to use a cycle to complete the cycle I can't get it working.

This is what I've tried:

```
<?php
$teacher1 = "teacher1";

echo " 
    <canvas id=\"lienzoGrafo\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\"></canvas>

    <script languaje=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"UTF-8\">
    var grafo = arbor.ParticleSystem({repulsion: 3000, friction:.1, stiffnes:900, gravity:true});
    grafo.renderer = Renderer(\"#lienzoGrafo\")";
    for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
        echo "grafo.addNode(\"teacher\".$i,{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:\"teacher\".$i})";
    }

    echo "</script>";

?>
```

But I can't get anything working, browser console outputs:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier localhost/:19`

But my `index.php` has the `</html>` tag at line 19.

I think problem is that html script statements are being rendered all together

```
grafo.renderer = Renderer("#lienzoGrafo")grafo.addNode("teacher0",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:"teacher0"})grafo.addNode("teacher1",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:"teacher1"})grafo.addNode("teacher2",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:"teacher2"})grafo.addNode("teacher3",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:"teacher3"})grafo.addNode("teacher4",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:"teacher4"})</script>
```

Comment: Why not round off each segment of code with the closing `?>` tag, then just put your script as normal.

Comment: `languaje` may have something to do with it. Also it looks like the only php there is the loop. I'd just do the php there versus echoing the whole script

Comment: You really should look into using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) to do multiline echo/assignments. That or break out of PHP mode and simply stick with html mode. Either will save you from having to escape all the quotes in the text.

Comment: You could suggest an example as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I realized the rendered html had JavaScripts statements all together, **I just added a semicolon (`;`) to JavaScript statements.**

```
grafo.renderer = Renderer(\"#lienzoGrafo\");";
```

and

```
echo "grafo.addNode(\"teacher" . $i . "\",{color:'blue',width:50, shape:'dot',label:\"teacher" . $i . "\"});";
```

did the trick!

> **My learning**
>
> > - Always look for the `html` `php` generates.
> > - It's not always a good idea to end a Script statement without semicolon.
> > - Only use php when it's precisely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your for loop ...

```
echo "grafo.addNode(\"teacher" . $i . "\",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:\"teacher" . $i . "\"})";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "grafo.addNode(\"teacher$i\",{color:'blue' etc...
                             ^^---note the position
```

As written, your PHP code is generating

```
grafo.addNode("teacher"7,{color:etc....
                       ^---syntax error
```

Comment: I changed it to `echo "grafo.addNode(\"teacher" . $i . "\",{color:'blue',width:100, shape:'dot',label:\"teacher" . $i . "\"})";` as other asnwer suggested but I got not results. Check my edit, I think the reason of it is how html is being rendered.

Comment: then do a view-source on your page and look at the actual output of your server-side code. don't debug in the dark. you'll see exactly where the syntax errors are.